# If I have the Android version of Minecraft, can I get the Windows 10 version cheaply or for free?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I've purchased the Android version of *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* for my son to play on his tablet then found all sorts of articles saying that purchasing it entitles one also to get the Windows version but can't figure out how.

Comment: It costs the same for Minecraft Java Edition as it does for Minecraft: Windows 10 edition, but if you buy the Java Edition Microsoft gives you a code for getting the Windows 10 Edition for free. If you have the Java Edition already you should have a code that can be used for the Windows 10 Edition (unless you already used it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock)

Comment: @pppery Voting to leave open. I believe [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389361/4797) is about the PC versions only, while this is talking about the Android version. Different question, different answers.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote given your edit to the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Mojang Support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-windows-10-edition), only players that have purchased the Java edition of the game before October 19<sup>th</sup> 2018 can get the Windows 10 edition for free:

> Players who have purchased Minecraft: Java Edition before October 19th, 2018 can get Minecraft for Windows 10 for free by visiting their Mojang account. Log into [account.mojang.com](https://account.mojang.com/login), and under the “My Games” heading you will find a button to claim your gift code. If you purchased Minecraft: Java Edition after October 19th, 2018, the button will not be there...

As far as I know, there is only one official way to get the game, and that is through the Windows/Microsoft store.  Unless it goes on sale, I don't think there is anyway to get it cheaper.

Comment: That being said, I think in the near future, a [big update](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Better_Together_Update) is planned for PE, Consoles, and the Windows 10 edition, which is suppose to add cross platform play between consoles (that is the Xbox One and Nintendo Switch), PE, and Windows 10 editions.  There may be some sort of special for when this happens - so it may be worth holding out.

Comment: On a semi-related note: Even if you own the Pocket Edition for Windows Phone, you still need to buy the Windows 10 Edition at full price. Also, the Windows 10 Edition only works on PC, not Windows 10 Mobile, so people who want the game on phone **and** PC have no other choice than to buy the game twice, regardless of platform.