# If I have Minecraft on mobile can I have the windows 10 edition for free?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, pc, windows-10, microsoft-store

## Context

I have MCPE on mobile and mostly play it on controller.

After playing other PC games (like krunker) I thought to start playing on my laptop (main reason is that I am getting a new beefy PC)

> P.S I have actually brought Minecraft from the Playstore And thus have a ligit Microsoft account linked with MC

## Main Problem

I want to know if it possible to play the windows 10 edition of Minecraft if I have my Microsoft account linked with my Minecraft PE Android application.

## My Thoughts

I think there might be two methods.

***1:***

> If my Microsoft account (let's say it is `ex@gmail.com`) is linked to my MCPE and I signed my Microsoft store account with the same account `ex@gmail.com` it will be free

***2***

> I have all MCPE files in my phone. Can I transfer it to PC and play (of course not ) my Android files are .APK and and windows supports .EXE files so I think either I get an Android emulator (has very slim chances of working now that I think about it) or convert my APK file to EXE file (problem is I can't find my Minecraft.APK file)

## Ending

Plz tell me if any of my methods will work.

P.S: I am a stack-overflow user on PC but wrote this in phone so plz forgive any formatting mistakes or spelling mistakes and/or unclear sentences

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/317398/143571

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Wrigglenite's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play the Windows 10 Edition, you still have to buy it even if you have the mobile game with a microsoft account. I have bedrock edition on my phone, Nintendo Switch, and Xbox, and I have always had to buy Minecraft on each device.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for the info.